# how to write wordpress query for multiple metakeys checking?

Tags: wp-query, database

My database contain two players
called Player A And Player B
both are same dress size and color
i store record in database like that

```
wo_postmeta.metakey='jersy color' & metavalue=1
wo_postmeta.metakey='teamnumbr' & metavalue="20"
select record where
wo_postmeta.metakey='jersy color' & metavalue=1 AND 
wo_postmeta.metakey='teamnumbr'
and collect player name from wp_post like post_title
```

I want to show its name and teamnumber.
How to write query for them?
Please Guide Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hard to guess, what exactly are you trying to achieve, because your code isn't correct SQL, but...

It looks like you want to select posts based on custom fields... So all you need to do is to use `Meta_Query`.

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',  // <- or whatever post type you're searching
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // <- let's get all of such posts
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'jersy color',
            'value' => '1',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'teamnumbr',
            'value' => '20',
        ), 
    )
) );
```

Comment: Please Check this query

Comment: $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'wpcf-fct-jersey-red' AND meta_value = '1' AND post_id IN (".$team_ids."))AND meta_key = 'wpcf-number' AND meta_value != ''");

Comment: and also want to post title from wp_post table